# Call from .env file laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my `.env` file, I created a variable

```
TEST_ENV = false
```

Now I want to do a check for this variable in `blade.php`, and if the value matches display the code

I do like this

```
@if(env('TEST_ENV') = false)
    <!-- some code --> 
    <h1>Test</h1>
@endif
```

But I get the error

> Can't use the function return value in write context

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` also `@if(env('TEST_ENV') == false)`

Comment: `env('TEST_ENV') = false` a single equals is an assignment, a double-equals is a comparison. You can actually simplify it and remove confusion by doing `@if(!env('TEST_ENV'))`